# Read file and tokenize by strtok in c

Tags: c, file, strtok

In this program, I want to read a file and convert that into string and tokenize them with whitespace, \n, comma, and + but I am getting infinite execution of the first line

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char ch,buff[500],bb[500];
int i=0;
fp=fopen("i.c","r");
if(fp==NULL) printf("File not opened");
else{
    printf("File opened successfully\n");
    ch=getc(fp);
    while(ch!=EOF){
        fgets(buff,500,fp);
       strcat(bb,buff);
    ch=getc(fp);
 }
char *tok=strtok(bb,"\n ,+=");
while(tok!=NULL){
printf("%s",tok);
tok=strtok(bb,"\n ,+=");
}
}
}
```

This is my file which I am reading i.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int num1=5,num2=6,num3;
char str[10]="hello";
num3=num1+num2;
printf("%s:%d",str,num3);
}
```

Comment: The code has several mistakes. Not initialising `bb` before `strcat(bb,buff);`. Wrong use of subsequent calls to `strtok` (should be `NULL` argument). Wrong way to loop using `fgets`. No need for additional `getc`. Unfinished logic after failed `fopen`.

Comment: Sir, please see the code again. I have initialized bb below file pointer. Any help further will be appreciated @Weather Vane

Comment: Sorry there is no initialising of `bb`. Function`strcat` requires a nul terminated string to append to. Local variables do not get automatic initialisation - you have to do it yourself, such as with `char bb[500] = "";`

Comment: see this line int main()
{
FILE *fp;
char ch,buff[500],bb[500];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution:

- should not use  `while(ch!=EOF)` as it has unexpected behaviour.
- Use fscanf to read line. with `ret` integer which will return EOF if the file is ended or `0` if line is not scanned into the variable
- while getting tokens you should pass NULL instead of the pointer. `tok=strtok(NULL,"\n ,+=");` instead of `tok=strtok(bb,"\n ,+=");`
  Code:

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<string.h>    
  int main()
  {
      FILE *fp;
      char ch,line[500],bb[1000] = ""; // initialize bb
      int i=0,ret;
      fp=fopen("i.c","r");
      if(fp==NULL) printf("File not opened");
      else
      {
          printf("File opened successfully\n");
          while(ret = fscanf(fp," %s ", line))   // use of fscanf
          {
              if(ret == EOF)
              {
                  break;
              }

              strcat(bb,line);
              strcat(bb,"\n");
          }

          char *tok=strtok(bb,"\n ,+=");
          while(tok!=NULL)
          {
              printf("%s",tok);
              tok=strtok(NULL,"\n ,+=");   // NULL instead of pointer
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  #### strtok in c:
- A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.
- On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new starting location for scanning.

reference:

- [strtok in c](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)
- [strtok document](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: why are you using this tok=strtok(NULL,"\n ,+=");

Comment: check the reference i added below.

Comment: In the site :: On a first call, the function expects a C string as argument for str, whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for tokens. In subsequent calls, the function expects a null pointer and uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new starting location for scanning.